# Fan continuously running without any load

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, hardware

On my MacBook Air (2017 model), fan is continuously running at > 6k RPM without any high load (< 20% CPU load). I have reseted SMC multiple times but to no avail. I am out of warranty period and I am afraid I will have to take it to Apple Service Centre.

Comment: Every once in a while my fan runs high for an extended period of time and when I notice it, I just put the system to sleep for a moment, the fan cuts out, then I wake the system back up. It's a minor inconvenience but it's better than having to reboot. Click the Apple menu and then Sleep, wait a moment for it to sleep and the fan should spin down, then press the Space key to wake it back up.

Comment: Resetting SMC can be tricky, watch for the charger (Magsafe) light brief change to indicate it was successful.

Comment: This not a Joke. Put your Mac in Fridge and leave it there for 15 minutes.

Comment: @Buscar웃 Literally tried putting it in the refrigerator, no difference. Also, I noticed the MagSafe adapter go from orange to green for a moment and then again back to orange while resetting SMC. What else can I try before going to Apple store?

Comment: Sounds like a failure in the thermal monitoring, however this doesn't always point to an actual sensor failure or even failure of the SMC itself. Install a monitoring utility like HWSensors from SourceForge and take a look at the readings. If you have a single sensor that looks out-of-range that's the first place to start looking. If you have multiple sensor failures it's likely those sensors live on the same SMBus segment and sensor failure is unlikely. Report back and let us know if it's a single or multiple failure. Apple will want to replace the board regardless but independents can help.

Comment: What else you ask, well not much and it depends on your budget. Now you know it is actually not overheating, you could just live with it. The fan will be fine, it is designed for it. If you want to, you could take the battery out for a while.

Comment: I almost forgot, run the Apple Hardware Test just to see the report. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257

Comment: Before I leave you in your misery (sorry) you can continue to poke around your self, using 3d party utility tools like iStat app ($10), and my favorite from Intel them self ($free) , https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-power-gadget-20 to learn more. Or even this one https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/47386/macs-fan-control

Comment: @stillanoob, I strongly suggest that you have a look at [Will it damage my MacBook if I put it in the fridge to cool it down?](https://superuser.com/questions/1091712/will-it-damage-my-macbook-if-i-put-it-in-the-fridge-to-cool-it-down)! In short, the temperature differential has the potential to and or can/could/will cause condensing condensation when removed, much less the initial thermal shock when first putting it in there, either of which can lead to a catastrophic logic board or other component failure!

Comment: Just wanted to post an update. Didn't use my Mac for about a week as I was busy. Logged in a couple days back. Everything seems to be fine. Weird!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is essentially a thermal monitoring failure and in all likelihood your CPU and GPU will be working within their thermal limits (in fact they will probably be running cooler than usual thanks to you fan running at 100% PWM). While this *can* be caused by a failed sensor or SMC it can *also* be caused by power issues close to the SMBus (which is responsible for simple communication between various hardware components). Take a look at this Louis Rossman video where a very similar issue is diagnosed (spoiler alert, surprisingly it turns out to be a faulty FaceTime camera causing the fan speed issue)...

[2014 MacBook thermal monitoring failure with fans running at maximum speed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g6ncbi0eGCQ)

The precise nature of the fault is largely academic as Apple will simply replace the logic board rather than attempt a component-level repair. An independent such as Rossmann may well be able to diagnose the fault and repair it at a reasonable price, but the only free/DIY option is to install software to bring your fan speeds under control and live with it.

If you want to pay for a repair you will need to use a monitoring utility to give you an idea of whether it's a single or multiple sensor failure. I use [HWSensors](https://sourceforge.net/projects/hwsensors/) as it's free, works and gives comprehensive system information, but any of the other suggested utilities should give you the feedback you need. You'll definitely be wanting to check **both** CPU and GPU temperatures look to be within normal limits at idle, if either is obviously too high or low then the SMC will default to maximum fan speeds to ensure nothing cooks, regardless of whether it's actually cooking or not.

My choice of utility to bring fan speeds under control is [Macs Fan Control](https://github.com/crystalidea/macs-fan-control/releases), this allows you to define your reference sensor and is also well-suited for all iMac models with custom hard disk firmware which causes the system fans to run at full speed when a non-Apple drive is fitted. This is also arguably superior to the standard OS X thermal control in that it lets you set up a thermal plan to suit you rather than having to live with Apple's predefined thermal-acoustic balance.

If you want a simpler interface then [SSD Fan Control](https://exirion.net/ssdfanctrl/) may be more up your street.